# ConcurrentHashMap update exists value thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I want to use the concurrent hash map holding some results,

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Long,AtomicInteger>
```

add a new entry if key not exists,or get value by key and increment,like this:

```
if(map.contains(key))
  map.get(key).addAndGet(1);
else
  map.put(key,new AtomicInteger(1));
```

the put operation is not thead safe,how to solve this problem? Is put operation should within synchronized block?

Comment: It's not just the put operation - the entire conditional block shown would have to be in a synchronized block. Alternatively you could use `putIfAbsent`.

Comment: Using the putIfAbsent seems more simple. I used the the double check in synchronized block instead of using in  entire conditional block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `put()` operation itself is implemented in a threadsafe way, i.e. if you put the same key it will be synchronized internally.

The call, however, isn't, i.e. two threads could add a new key simultaneously. You could try `putIfAbsent()` and if you get a return value (i.e. not null) you could call the get method. Thus you could change your code like this:

```
//this only adds a new key-value pair if there's not already one for the key
if( map.putIfAbsent(key,new AtomicInteger(1)) != null ) {    
  map.get(key).addAndGet(1);
}
```

Alternatively if you're using Java 8 you could use the `compute()` method which according to the JavaDoc is performed atomically. The function you pass would then check whether the value already exists or not. Since the whole call is synchronized you probably wouldn't even need to use a `AtomicInteger` (depends on what else you are doing with the value).

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you could use ConcurrentHashMap's [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to provide initial value:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, new AtomicInteger(0)).addAndGet(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(K key, V value)` and pay attention to the return value.